# Minimize function defined by script

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, minimize

Suppose I have a function in Matlab `calc(x,a,b)` which outputs a scalar. `a` and `b` are constants, `x` is treated as multivariate. How do I minimize `calc(x,a,b)` with respect to `x` in Matlab?

edit: The content of the function creates a vector $v(x)$ and a matrix $A(x)$ and then computes $v(x)'*A(x)^(-1)*v(x)$

Comment: By _multidimensional_ do you mean a generic `M`-by-`N` matrix? If it is so, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly general question with a million possible responses depending on what `calc` is. (For instance,  Can you provide gradients for `calc`? Does `x` need to take on values in a specific range?)

But, as a start, go for [fminunc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html). It is for functions where you have no gradient information available and you want to find an unconstrained minimum.

---

**Sample Code:**
Suppose you want to minimize `dot(x,x)`.

```
calc = @(x,a,b) dot(x,x)
calc_to_pass_to_fminunc = @(x) calc(x,1,2)
X = fminunc(calc_to_pass_to_fminunc,ones(3,1))
```

Gives:

```
Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm;
  using line-search algorithm instead. 
> In fminunc at 383 

Local minimum found.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>


X =

     0
     0
     0
```

Comment: The content of the function creates a vector $v(x)$ and a matrix $A(x)$ and computes $v(x)'*A(x)^-1*v(x)$

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is: if `a` and `b` are constants, and `x` is a one-dimensional variable, it's a 1-D optimization problem.

The previous answer suggests to use`fminunc`, which is part of the MATLAB Optimization Toolbox. If you don't have it, you can use [`fminbnd`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) instead of it, which works just well in case of 1-D optimization in a given interval.

As example, let's say your `calc` function is:

```
function [y] = calc(x,a,b)
y = x.^3-2*x-5+a-b;
end
```

This is what you should do to find the minimum in the interval `x1 < x < x2`:

```
% constants
a = 1; 
b = 2;

% boundaries of search interval
x1 = 0; 
x2 = 2;
x = fminbnd(@(x)calc(x,a,b), x1, x2);

% value of function at the minimum
y = calc(x,y,a);
```

In the case of the `x` variable not being a scalar, you could use the analogous of `fminbnd` for a multidimensional variable: [`fminsearch`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), which performs an unconstrained search for the minimum of a multivariate function.

---

### Addendum

`fminbnd` is a nice tool, but sometimes it's hard to make it behave as you expect. Of course you can specify the desired accuracy and a maximum number of iterations for converging in the options, but in my experience `fminbnd` might have problems with highly non-linear functions.

In these situations it's desirable to have a finer control on the optimization procedure, and especially on how it's defined the search interval. Given the search interval, [`arrayfun`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) provides an elegant way to iterate over an array for finding a minimum of the function. Sample code:

```
% constants
a = 1; 
b = 2;

% search interval
xi = linspace(0,2,1000); 
yi = arrayfun(@(x)calc(x,a,b), xi);

% value of function at the minimum
[y, idx_m] = min(yi);

% location of minimum
x = xi(idx_m);
```

The drawback of this approach is that, in order to achieve a high accuracy, you might need a very long array `xi`. Good thing is that there are several ways to mitigate this issue: for instance, one could use a vector of log-spaced sampling points, or perform a multi-step minimization narrowing and increasing the sampling frequency at each step until the desired accuracy is achieved.

Comment: How do you surpress any fminsearch display output. The following does not help:
x0=initial constant;
options = optimset('Display', 'off');
banana= @(x) calc(x,constants);
[x,fval] = fminsearch(banana,x0,options);

Comment: Mine has a content :) I have found a way though by typing warning('off');